# Cannot select * from view in Hue/hive

Tags: sql, select, view, hive, hue

I am trying to select * from a view:

Ex:

```
SELECT * from `histdb_v3_nz_histusr`.`vw__hist_column_access_3_final` LIMIT 100;
```

and it throws me the below error.
I have tried to place the brackets on different places but still the same.
[image]

when I want to select the view from the source:

Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM `histdb_v3_nz_histusr`.`vw__hist_column_access_3` LIMIT 100;
```

It works.

Do you have any idea what is causing this error, I was searching but couldnt find any solution?

Comment: then the view is faulty

Comment: You can not create a table in hive that starts with `_`. So view you are trying to access is using an object whoose name starts with `_`. View `vw__hist_column_access_3_final` definition is wrong - you need to correct it.